# Sending part of byte array over the network using WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, binary, byte

I have a byte array of some binary data that i need to send over the network using WCF and NetTcpBinding. My problem is that i need to send only the part of the array. Is there any way to do this, other than copying that part to a separate array, and sending that one. This extra copying degrades performance, and i would like to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: If you are sending any data over the network, it would copied several times anyway. Copying part of data in current process' userspace should cause minimal overhead comparing to everything else. 

Have you measured whether this overhead is really significant?

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, the performance hit of the copy operation will be negligible in the context of a WCF call.

Use Array.Copy which seems to perform really well.

Comment: I was wondering how WCF sends List<byte>, for example. List<byte> internally holds an array of bytes. Does it send the whole byte array or just the number of bytes actually used in the list (capacity or count). I need something like that.

Comment: You are not going to gain performance by using a more abstract collection class -  it will still need to do array copy operations internally.